# Quantifying pixels from a list of coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have a list of coordinates, which are generated from another program, and I have an image.

I'd like to load those coordinates (making circular regions of interest (ROIs) with a diameter of 3 pixels) onto my image, and extract the intensity of those pixels.

I can load/impose the coordinates on to the image by using;

```
imshow(file);
hold on
scatter(xCoords, yCoords, 'g')
```

But can not extract the intensity.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you post a sample image and sample coordinates with the expected output, please (i.e. an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will definitely help you getting a useful answer.

Comment: `pixeldata=file(xCoords,yCoords)`?

Comment: @AnderBiguir Thanks a lot, its almost working

I used 
'a = imread(file);'
pixeldata = a(xCoords, yCoords);'

I used a matrix (padded the single coordinate value +/- 3 pixels in the X and Y directions) to extract a larger (square) ROI than the exact pixel...but haven't worked out how to extract data from a circular region.

A small problem is that imread does not provide the 16 bit values.

Comment: How do you extract "circular region"? The pixels are in a square grid! Still you shoudl be able to get the ones that are further than a given R distance easy. Imread provides 16bit values if the image is 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by a circle with 3 pixels diameter since you are in a square grid (as mentioned by [Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri)). But you could use `fspecial` to create a disk filter and then normalize. Something like this:

```
r = 1.5; % for diameter = 3
h = fspecial('disk', r);
h = h/h(ceil(r),ceil(r));
```

You can use it as a mask to get the intensities at the given region of the image.

```
im = imread(file);
ROI = im(xCoord-1:xCoord+1; yCoord-1:yCoord+1);
I = ROI.*h;
```